# Hibernate: OutOfMemoryError persisting Blob when printing log message

Tags: hibernate, blob, stringbuilder, pretty-print, out-of-memory

I have a Hibernate Entity:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    //...
    @Lob
    public byte[] getBytes() { return bytes; }
    //....
}
```

My VM is configured with a maximum heap size of 512 MB.  When I try to persist an object which has a 75 MB large object, I get an OutOfMemoryError.

The names of the methods in the stack trace (StringBuilder, ByteArrayBlobType.toLoggableString, pretty.Printer.toString) suggest that hibernate is trying to write a very large log message that contains my object.

Am I correct about why hibernate is using so much memory?  What is the simplest way to work around this problem?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:44)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:81)
at org.hibernate.type.ByteArrayBlobType.toString(ByteArrayBlobType.java:117)
at org.hibernate.type.ByteArrayBlobType.toLoggableString(ByteArrayBlobType.java:127)
at org.hibernate.pretty.Printer.toString(Printer.java:53)
at org.hibernate.pretty.Printer.toString(Printer.java:90)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:97)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernateSessionProxy.flush(HibernateSessionProxy.java:181)
```

Comment: Did you disable logging for hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.  Turning off logging did fix the problem, but I didn't understand that when running under the JBoss application server, the server's own log4j.xml file overrides whatever I put the in classpath of the application.

I opened up /jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/conf/log4.xml, and inserted this:

```
<category name="org.hibernate">
    <priority value="ERROR"/>
</category>
```

This fixes the issue I am seeing.

Comment: If you want to fix this and still have hibernate debug messages:
<category name="org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener">
  <priority value="INFO" />
 </category>

Answer (score 0):

The first test is to see if it really is a logging issue.  What logger are you using?  If it's log4j, then you can try to turn off all logging from Hibernate with the following line in your log4j.properties file:

> log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF

That might not be the ultimate, ideal way for your app to operate, but it might help you test whether logging is the issue.

Comment: @delfuego: Thanks for the tip about how to disable it.  I created an empty file in the root of my classpath and added that line to it, and I'm still getting a lot of messages that come from hibernate in the console, for example:

12:44:42,530 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: /* select o from Permission o */ select permission0_.id as id21_, permission0_

I will go look for some info about how to disable logging, since this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The pretty printer is probably converting the bytes to hex notation (e.g. '0x55 0xF3 ...)', so for each byte in the blob you get 4 bytes of output so 300M of output, that and buffering, with other stuff in your VM probably puts you over the limit.

Comment: That's what I am thinking.  Now I just need to know how to turn that "feature" off.  :)

Comment: How about the Hibernate properties hibernate.show_sql=false and 
hibernate.format_sql=false ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try the following two Hibernate properties?

```
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
```