# Out of Memory Error in hibernate when querying a table with large data

Tags: java, hibernate

I am Querying a table using *Hibernate* by i get the error

```
"Exception in thread 
"Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at  
    java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3222) at
     java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3222)".
```

Here is My sample code.

```
 public   List<MyBean> loadData() {
    Session s=CFactory.getSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
     List<MyBean> mybean=null;
    try {
      Query sry=s.createQuery("from MyBean where flag='NP'");
       mybean=sry.list();
     s.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mybean;
}
```

My question is how can i query in a table that has a huge data and convert it to a list without getting out of memory error in hibernate?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3222)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3222)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.DataHelper.extractBytes(DataHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.DataHelper.extractBytes(DataHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDesciptor.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$5.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
```

Comment: Firstly why are you using transaction while you are only fetching records from db??? and also can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: Increase your heap memory. -Xms and -Xmx are the one's which you needed!

Comment: @hemanth This might be related to hibernate logging feature. So you can't be sure about that. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487221/hibernate-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: it depends on the size that the query returns! ofcorse it also depends on the type of the content that is stored(BLOB,etc..)

Comment: @Vimal Bera I have posted the stacktrace

Comment: Use Pagination feature and load more data on request, If you dnt have sufficient system memory.

Comment: @Hemanth What can I do to solve this problem because the table contains images too

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not load a large table into memory at one time, use pagination is a must.

Comment: How can i implement that in hibernate

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Query sry=s.createQuery("from MyBean where flag='NP'")
.setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(pageSize);
```

for pagination.

Or you can [increase heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566026/876739)

Comment: Then how to i compine the paginated results into one bean?

Comment: If you are fetchin data only for dislpay purpose then you can use thsi

Comment: You can use Pagination      .